# How to use an event handler to click and display data in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I am trying to build a simple JavaScript calculator. I am having issues with the functioning part. I can't get the numbers to appear on the display screen and I am also having issues with the event handlers which I can get all the numbers to click.

HTML

```
<form name="calculator">

    <div class="calculator_container">

<table id="calculator">
    <caption>
        <input type="text" name="display" id="display" maxlength="40">
    </caption>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="AC" class="btn" id="allClear"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="C" class="btn" id="clear"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="+/-" class="btn" id="plusMinus"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="/" class="btn" id="operate"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="seven" value="7" class="btn" id="number"></td>

        <td><input type="button" name="eight" value="8" class="btn" id="number"></td>

        <td><input type="button" name="nine" value="9" class="btn" id="number"></td>

        <td><input type="button" value="x" class="btn" id="operator"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td><input type="button" name="four" value="4" class="btn" id="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="five"  value="5" class="btn" id="number" ></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="six"  value="6" class="btn" id="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="-" class="btn" id="operator"></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="one"  value="1" class="btn" id="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="two"  value="2" class="btn" id="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="three"  value="3" class="btn" id="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="+" class="btn" id="operator"></td>


    </tr>



    <tr>

        <td><input type="button" name="zero"  value="0" class="btn" id="number"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="." class="btn" id="dot"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="=" class="btn" id="calculate"></td>


    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

JS

```
let memory = "0";
let current = "0";
let operation = 0;
let maxLength = 30; 


const addDigit = (dig) => {
    if (current.length > maxLength){ 
    current = "Aargh! Too long"; //limit length
       } else { if ((eval(current) == 0) && (current.indexOf(".") == -1)
            ){ current = dig;
           } else { current = current + dig;

           };
    }; };
   document.calculator.display.value = current;
   document.getElementById("number").addEventListener("click", addDigit);





const dot = () => {
    if (current.length == 0) {
        current = "0.";
    } else {
        if (current.indexOf(".") == -1) {
            current = current + ".";
        };
    };

}
    document.calculator.display.value = current;
    document.getElementById("dot").addEventListener("click", dot);


const plusMinus = () => {
    if (current.indexOf("-") == 0) {
        current = current.substring(1);
    } else {
        current = "-" + current;
    };

    document.calculator.display.value = current;
}

    document.getElementById("plusMinus").addEventListener("click", plusMinus);


const clear = () => {
    current = "0";
    document.calculator.display.value = current;
}

    document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clear);


const allClear = () =>  {
    current = "0";
    operation = 0;
    memory = "0";
    document.calculator.display.value = current;
}

const operate = (op) => {
    if (op.indexOf("*") > -1) {operation = 1; };
    if (op.indexOf("/") > -1) {operation = 2; };
    if (op.indexOf("+") > -1) {operation = 3; };
    if (op.indexOf("-") > -1) {operation = 4; };

    memory = current;
    current = "";
    document.calculator.display.value = current;
}

    document.getElementById("operator").addEventListener("click", operate);


const calculate = () => {
    if (operation == 1) { current = eval(memory) * eval(current); };
    if (operation == 2) { current = eval(memory) / eval(current); };
    if (operation == 3) { current = eval(memory) + eval(current); };
    if (operation == 4) { current = eval(memory) - eval(current); };
    operation = 0;
    memory = "0";
    document.calculator.display.value = current;

}

    document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", calculate);

const fixCurrent = () =>  {
    current = document.calculator.display.value;
    current = "" + parseFloat(current);
    if (current.indexOf("NaN") != -1) {
        current = "Error!";
    };
    document.calculator.display.value = current;
}
```

I know there should an easy fix but I have reached a dead end and I would like some help completing this project.

Answer (score 0):

First off: an ID should ALWAYS be unique to each element.
You should also avoid using a form for each button, this feels like poor coding style to me. Simply use buttons. Moreover you should set the input box to readonly so the user cant input what he wants.

This is a minimal example that add an event handler to each button inside the wrapper div. You should make your way from there :)

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  var data = document.getElementById("data");
  data.value = data.value + event.target.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="data" readonly>
<div id="wrapper">
<button type="button" value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" value="2">2</button>
</div>
```